# Google Analytics always shows at least two page views per visit - What can cause this?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics on my wordpress blog, and I'm seeing some suspicious numbers:

- very low bounce rate (less than 1%)
- when doing the live view, I always see page views as a multiple of two

My other blogs do not show this behavior. My suspicion is that the page count is sent twice to google, but I have no idea why this would be the case.

I'm using a plugin called "Google Analyticator" to track my blog. To the best of my knowledge (I looked through my template's files), there are no "direct" calls to Google.

What can I do to further track down this issue?

Comment: Sounds like in your theme file you are maybe loading header or footer twice? Depends on where your code is placed. View source and look for tracking code - is it there just once?

Comment: I'm not sure where the plugin "calls" google, but I'll check. Also, how can I figure out if the header or footer is loaded twice?

Comment: After checking, it seems that the Analyticator adds to to the wp_head hook - which is called twice in my template (once with the comment "we need this for plugins"). Can I just remove the first (or second) call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a call to `wp_head` hook twice. Why does comments need its own call? Get rid of second call and see if that doesn't break anything.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough .. the second call to wp_hook looked like this: <?php wp_head(); //we need this for plugins ?>. I'll try removing and see if this breaks anything.